# Run function on "Place Order"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm building a custom checkout, that uses steps, like those used on Apple.

http://www.formisimo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Apple-stage-one.jpg

When an input field is marked as invalid, I would like the affected sections to expand again. I can't seem to get the function running on click though.

The test code is very basic. Any why this would not be working? It does work if I change the .click to use the body element, for example.

```
jQuery('#place_order').click(function(){

  if(jQuery('p#billing_last_name_field').hasClass('woocommerce-invalid')) {
    alert('INVALID');
  } else {
    alert('VALID');
  }

});
```

Comment: the trigger `('#place_order').click` is too soon, the validation is made later. try the trigger `$(document.body).on("update_checkout", ...`

Comment: generic JS, WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 3):

As it was already noted by @mmm, your click event is placed too soon. Try with a **submit trigger**, as suggested in a similar [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112407/2972183):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function() {
        ... your code here ...
    });
});
```

Comment: this gets the submit, but does not enable me to submit the real submit later on

is this possible?

I'd like to show a popup, and on completion I'd like to call the default woocommerce submit